# ¿Como adiciono una 2 clave foranea que a la vez son primarias?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo 2 tablas **COORDINACIÓN** y **NÚCLEO_ACADÉMICO**, la relación existente entre ellas es de direccion N:M(muchos a muchos), la estructura de la tabla **COORDINACIÓN** y **NÚCLEO_ACADÉMICO** la tabla es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE coordinacion (
idcoord int(11) NOT NULL,
nomcoord varchar(50) NOT NULL,
ubicacion varchar(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_coordinacion primary key(idcoord)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE nucleo_academico (
idnucleo int(11) NOT NULL,
nomnucleo varchar(150) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_nucleo_academico primary key(idnucleo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Hasta aqui todo bien, las tablas se crean normalmente, Ahora cuando procedo a crear la tabla de la relacion **OCUPA** para almacenar los respectivos campos, me arroja este error **"#1215 - No puede adicionar clave extranjera constraint"**, Aqui esta la estructura de la tabla **OCUPA:**

```
CREATE TABLE ocupa(
idcoord int(11) NOT NULL,
idnucleo int(11) NOT NULL,
foreign key(idcoord) REFERENCES coordinacion(idcoord),
foreign key(idnucleo) REFERENCES coordinacion(idnucleo),
primary key(idcoord,idnucleo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Agradeceria mucho que me den una mano con este problema, ya he cambiado varias cosas y corregido varios errores, solo me falta corregir esto para seguir avanzando con mi proyecto...

Comment: No hay ninguna columna `idnucleo` en su tabla `coordinacion` , quizá debería hacer referencia a su tabla `nucleo_academico`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es bastante simple, la columna `idnucleo` no existe en la tabla  `coordinacion` , referenciada al asignar su `foreign key`,debería hacer referencia a la tabla `nucleo_academico` en la cuál si existe dicha columna.

```
CREATE TABLE ocupa(
idcoord int(11) NOT NULL,
idnucleo int(11) NOT NULL,
foreign key(idcoord) REFERENCES coordinacion(idcoord),
foreign key(idnucleo) REFERENCES nucleo_academico(idnucleo),
primary key(idcoord,idnucleo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Oh no me percate de eso, muchas gracias!